# How to give two components their own State in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I have two buttons that upon click will update a counter. I want each button to update its own counter. How can I give each button its own state but at the same time use the same `onClick` method?

Here is what I have thus far?

```js
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import {Jumbotron,Badge, Glyphicon, Media, PageHeader, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

class UpVote extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }

    this.upVote = this.upVote.bind(this)
  }

  upVote() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    })
  }


 
  render() {
    const item = this.state.item
    return (
      <div>
       <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.upVote}>
             {this.state.count}
      </Button>
      <hr />
      <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.upVote}>
          {this.state.count}
      </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UpVote
```

Comment: If you use the upVote method from the UpVote component, you will always increase the state of the UpVote component. So how do you imagine to have a separate count on each Button but keep this method in both components?

Comment: That's why I asked the question. I am new to reactjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new button component that keeps track of its own state and then reuse it.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

class UpVoteButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }

    this.upVote = this.upVote.bind(this)
  }

  upVote() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.upVote}>
             {this.state.count}
      </Button>
    )
  }
}

export default UpVoteButton
```

And in the original component do:

```
import React from 'react'
import UpVoteButton from './UpVoteButton'

class UpVote extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UpVoteButton/>
        <hr />
        <UpVoteButton/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UpVote
```